# Rearranging $nk$ distinct objects among $n$ boxes, $k$ objects per box. Probability no box is the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The title is pretty self-explanatory as to what my question is, I think.

If we have distributed $nk$ distinct elements among $n$ boxes such that each box has $k$ objects in it, and we then randomly redistribute the objects so that each box still has $k$ objects, what is the probability that the contents of every box have changed?

My first thought was to compute the number of ways of rearranging the elements in which no box has the same contents as before via inclusion exclusion. My work is as follows:

For each $i \in [n]$, there are $n \choose i$$\frac{(nk-ik)!}{(k!)^{n-i}}$ ways of rearranging so that there are **at least** $i$ boxes which remained the same.

The total number of ways of rearranging is $\frac{(nk)!}{(k!)^n}$, (which is the multinomial $nk \choose k, k, ..., k$).

So the probability that we want is:

$\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}\frac{(nk-ik)!(k!)^i(-1)^i}{(nk)!}$

That is, unless I have made a mistake along the way. If my answer so far is correct, then here is the issue which I am having- I don't see how to simplify it further. Is it possible to find a closed form of the probability that we want here, or is my answer essentially as good as it gets?

Comment: "we then randomly redistribute the objects so that each box still has $k$ objects" What is the process of redistribution? do you continuously replace two elements in two boxes for $t$ times? or do you completely generate a new random distribution and compare it to the previously generated distribution?

Comment: We generate a new random distribution, so the latter of your two suggestions. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: you might know this already: the $k=1$ version of your problem is called Derangement.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement verifies that your formula is correctly for the $k=1$ case.  Very interestingly, the number of derangements has a (IMHO highly non-obvious) closed form solution involving nearest-integer to some expression involving $e$.  Not sure how / if they generalize to $k>1$, but that might be a way forward...?

Comment: Interesting, I had verified the $k = 1$ case already, but I failed to realize the connection to derangements. Will definitely look into that some more, although I am beginning to suspect that my professor did not expect us to find a closed form here. Might still be possible though. Thanks for the suggestion!